# How to set maxlength for fields in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
       maxfullname: 10,
      mobile: '',
      maxmobile: 10,
      area: '',
      maxarea: 12,
      city: '',
      maxcity: 12,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms || !this.fullname || !this.mobile || !this.area || !this.city;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms'/> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'  :maxlength="maxfullname"/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile'/ :maxlength="maxmobile"> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area' :maxlength="maxarea"/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city':maxlength="maxcity"/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
  <button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

At present i am having the issue like, In each field, if i enter 2 or 3 characters and  click on the button, button is enabling,
But trying for until user enter maxlength characters for all fields then only button should enabled

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to enter `maxlength` characters before the button is enabled? If so, that should be `minlength`. And your `isDisabled` computed prop could just check the length of all fields.

Comment: yes user should enter maxlength characters before the button enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `isDisabled` computed prop could return whether or not the fields meet the minimum lengths, as shown in the demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
       maxfullname: 10,
      mobile: '',
      maxmobile: 10,
      area: '',
      maxarea: 12,
      city: '',
      maxcity: 12,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms || (this.fullname.length < this.maxfullname) || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile) || (this.area.length < this.maxarea) || (this.city.length < this.maxcity);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms'/> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'  :maxlength="maxfullname"/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile' :maxlength="maxmobile"/> mobile
      <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area' :maxlength="maxarea"/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city':maxlength="maxcity"/> city
    </label>
  </p>
  <button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```